# jQuery Posting an Object

Tags: jquery, object, post

I've got an object defined like this:

```
 data = {name: 'durk durk durk', site_id: 123456}
```

And I've got a function that looks like this:

```
function(data) { jQuery.post('www.example.com/ajax', { method: 'add', data: data } )
```

Which would be awesome, except it's posting like this:

```
data[name]: durk durk durk
data[site_id]:  123456
method: add
```

When what I want is it to post like this:

```
name:   durk durk durk
site_id:    123456
method: add
```

So I thinks to myself, "Self, just take out that extra data and you'll be all set and your coworkers will think how clever you are with your fancy object post".

So I changed the function to this:

```
function(data) { jQuery.post('www.example.com/ajax', { method: 'add', data } )
```

Which failed spectacularly.

Please help me so I don't have to cry myself to sleep tonight.

Thanks.

Comment: <strike>You're posting this to where? PHP? You want to take an associative array and convert it to variable named after a key and pass the value? What does your server script look like, what do you mean you want it to "post like"?</strike> After reading the answers I see that my reading comprehension skills suck :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the big hammer:

```
data.method = 'add';
function(data) { jQuery.post('www.example.com/ajax', data) …
delete data.method;
```

The elegant way:

```
function(data) { jQuery.post('www.example.com/ajax', $.extend({}, data, {'method' : 'add'})) …
```

Comment: jQuery.extend() is much better than my suggestion actually.

Comment: Hate to say that, but: yap, it is. The primary reason is, that it doesn't require the OP to modify his pre-existent data structures.

Comment: Awesome! Still cried myself to sleep, but this time it was due to my terrible social skills instead of sub-par programming! Thanks!

ps: I am joking.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.extend` to combine the two objects.

```
data = {name: 'durk durk durk', site_id: 123456}
var postData = $.extend({}, data, { method: "add" });

function(postData) { jQuery.post('www.example.com/ajax', { postData } )
```